# Flutter: Is it neccessary to remove testdevice id from Firebase admob before publishing app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob

I'm using Firebase Admob in my Flutter application, I guess I need to remove the TestDevice id from the code. If yes then:

1. I'm a bit confused that if I need to remove the TestDevice id before publishing my app than what thing/code should replace it?
2. When I remove the TestDevice id from the app than it shows an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to remove test device id.

Using test device id means your ads will be displayed as test ads in your device which is what Google suggest you, never run your own ads in your device, or your account may be suspended on doing so cause you'll be creating fake impressions.

So, the bottom line is to keep using test device id no matter if it is for development or production. Only your test device will see test ads. End users will see real ad.